# Copy Shape (picture) to another workbook makes picture saved as JPEG instead of PNG

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that loops through each shape in one worksheet in Workbook A to copy to a worksheet in Workbook B. The problem is that the copied picture / shape changes from PNG to JPEG, which means the Excel file increases in size from 12MB to 20MB (based on looking in the ZIP-file).

```vb
'Set Account Worksheets
Set ImportAccountDocumentationWorksheet = ImportWorkbook.Worksheets("D" & AccountNo)
Set AccountDocumentationWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("D" & AccountNo)
    
'Process Each Shape
For Each CurrentShape In ImportAccountDocumentationWorksheet.Shapes
    CurrentShape.Copy
    Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) 'Avoids Copy-Paste timing issue
    AccountDocumentationWorksheet.Range(CurrentShape.TopLeftCell.Address).PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)
Next CurrentShape
```

Is it possible to copy the shape / picture without the change in file format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed possible.

I think whats messing up the formatting is the `Worksheet.Range.PasteSpecial` method, to get around this I just used `Worksheet.Paste` in this solution:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)
#End If

Sub MoveShapes()
    Dim SourceWS As Worksheet
    Dim TargetWS As Worksheet
    
    Set SourceWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyWorksheet")
    Set TargetWS = Application.Workbooks("MyOtherWorkbook.xlsm").Worksheets("MyOtherWorksheet")
    
    Dim ImageTop As Long
    Dim ImageLeft As Long
    
    Dim CurrentShape As Shape
    Dim TargetShp As Shape

    'Process Each Shape
    For Each CurrentShape In SourceWS.Shapes
        ImageTop = CurrentShape.Top
        ImageLeft = CurrentShape.Left
        Sleep 100
        CurrentShape.Copy
        Sleep 100
        TargetWS.Paste

        'Adjust position of the last added shape
        Set TargetShp = TargetWS.Shapes(TargetWS.Shapes.Count)
        TargetShp.Top = ImageTop
        TargetShp.Left = ImageLeft
    Next CurrentShape
End Sub
```

#### Other option:

Should this not work, or you just want to convert all the pictures to .png, you can use the next piece of code. Here, all shapes are temporarily exported to a .png file and then reimported in the other worksheet:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lngMilliSeconds As Long)
#End If

Sub MoveShapes()
    'Specify source and target worksheets
    Dim SourceWS As Worksheet
    Dim TargetWS As Worksheet
    
    Set SourceWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyWorksheet")
    Set TargetWS = Application.Workbooks("MyOtherWorkbook.xlsm").Worksheets("MyOtherWorksheet")
    
    Dim ImageLeft As Long
    Dim ImageTop As Long
    Dim ImageWidth As Long
    Dim ImageHeight As Long
    Dim tempChrt As ChartObject
    Dim CurrentShape As shape
    
    For Each CurrentShape In SourceWS.Shapes
        'caching image dimensions
        ImageLeft = CurrentShape.Left
        ImageTop = CurrentShape.Top
        ImageWidth = CurrentShape.Width
        ImageHeight = CurrentShape.Height     
        
        'creating a temporary ChartObject necessare for exporting
        Set tempChrt = SourceWS.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=ImageLeft, Width:=ImageWidth, _
                       Top:=ImageTop, Height:=ImageHeight)
        
        tempChrt.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
        tempChrt.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
        
        'Copying the shape into the ChartObject 
        '(sleep is used instead of Application.Wait)
        'If copy errors occur, just increase the sleep time a little
        Sleep 100
        CurrentShape.Copy
        tempChrt.Activate
        Sleep 100
        ActiveChart.Paste
        
        'Exporting the shape as .png
        tempChrt.Chart.Export FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.png", FilterName:="png"
        tempChrt.Delete
        
        'Reimporting in target workbook as png
        TargetWS.Shapes.AddPicture ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.png", msoFalse, _
                                   msoCTrue, ImageLeft, ImageTop, ImageWidth, ImageHeight
        
        'Deleting temporary file
        Kill ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.png"
    Next CurrentShape
End Sub
```

If your source shapes are not pictures but rather native excel shapes or other vector graphics, this method will convert them all to .png.